# What is the alternative for window.performance.getEntries(); in FireFox and Safari?

Tags: performance, firefox, browser, safari

IE and Chrome offer window.performance.getEntries(); to get information about performance of entities in a webpage.

In both FireFox and Safari, this command is undefined when I try to use it from the console.

So, my question is: what is the alternative in FireFox and Safari for this functionality?

**EDIT:**

I'm using this command via Javascript. Hence I need an alternative also for other browsers.

Comment: Gari, I deleted my earlier answer as I found out I was incorrect. Sorry for any confusion I created.

Answer (score 0):

CanIUse says something for resource timing (which is part of what youre asking): http://caniuse.com/#search=resource timing

Also it says

This feature can be enabled in about:config, search for `dom.enable_resource_timing` flag

By default it is turned off, you'll have to ask your users to switch it on manually, or to write a [plugin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Overlay_Extensions/XUL_School/Handling_Preferences#Adding_preferences_to_an_extension) for this purpose

Comment: @Kaiido But I can't turn on this flag via JS if this flag is already turned off...

Comment: @GariBN No, by default this feature is turned off, you'll have to ask your users to switch it on manually, or to write a [plugin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Overlay_Extensions/XUL_School/Handling_Preferences) for this purpose… As others pointed out, maybe telling us why you do need this function will help us find you a better alternative

Answer (score 0):

Now `window.performance.getEntries();` works fine in Firefox, but the problem remains for Safari.